# Бага при запуске mysql-workbench в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, mysql-workbench

При запуске mysql-workbench возникает ошибка

https://gist.github.com/vasilukwolf/5d820b5d675c8e7fe1c67ee3b0665d96

Это похоже на багу этого года, которую пытается решить ORACLE

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24072

Вроде бы пишут, что если что-то сделать с версиеё gcc, то пакет должен заработать. Кто-нибудь уже хотфиксил эту проблему? Какие есть варианты кроме переустановки и чистки workbench, так как они не помогают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помогло только:

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-workbench 
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get clean
```

И установка из официального источника deb:

> https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Answer (score 1):

можно проще: 
rm ~/.mysql/workbench/wb_options.xml

Comment: А ещё проще 'rm -rf /'. Обоснуйте пожалуйста ваш ответ.

Comment: rm ~/.mysql/workbench/wb_options.xml сработало